# Scoring by dynamic data in Solr or Elastics

Tags: elasticsearch, solr-boost

I have a list of business documents in my `Solr`. Every business has a location, a rating, and multiple discount plans. Now I use `Solr` for suggesting the best rated and nearest business for every users. It works great.
My plan is adding discount to search query.

Every businesses has 4 discount plan.
`Biz1 ====> Paln0=0%, Plan1=5%, Plan2=10%, Plan3=15%`
`Biz2 ====> Plan0=0%, Plan1=2%, Plan2=5%, Plan3=7%`
This data is saved on `Solr` documents.

Every user has her own discount plan for every one of this business.
`User1 ===> Biz1=Plan1, Biz2=Plan3`
`User2 ===> Biz1=Plan3, Biz2=Plan2`
This data is saved on my database.

I want to add discount to `Solr` score, but for every user this discount is different! Simply, by removing location and rating from score, it will only be discount and the result of the above example for `User1` and `User2` must be:
`User1
1-Biz2 7%
2-Biz1 5%`

`User2
1-Biz1 15%
2-Biz2 5%`

Is there any solution for my problem on `Solr` or `Elasticsearch`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here:

1. Which plans a user has for which business?
2. How to use the right business plan to rank the documents.

The first problem can be solved by querying the database to get your business => plan query. 
The second can be solved by ElasticSearch's function score.

You could boost on business document that have one of the plans.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {},
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "plan0"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight":5
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "plan1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight":10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By querying the database I can find that the user is registered on which plan of every businesses, but all businesses has 4 plan for discount and in second query the score of every business (discount score) is depend on that the user is registered on which discount plan of this business. But on your query it's depend on that if business has that plan! It does not work for me!